# PHP will not run unless 644?

Tags: php, configuration, permissions, server, cpanel

I am sub-contracted through a large data center that uses shared servers and cPanel. I create websites for their hosting clients.

Their configuration is off. When I upload files to the server through cPanel directories are given 775 permissions and PHP files are given 664 permissions.

Every time I upload an application I have to recursively change the file permissions of the PHP files from 664 to 644 or no PHP will execute and results in a 500 error.

This is particularly painful because as a sub-contractor I have to ask for temporary shell access every time I need to do this.

Obviously the problem is that the PHP files are being executed by the group, and 664 permissions do not allow execution.

I'm not too familiar with cPanel, and I'm unsure what is causing this problem. Is this a problem with the server, or with cPanel? How can I change the default upload permissions for cPanel?

Comment: Why would php files need executable permissions?

Comment: I guess I don't know. I assumed that they needed the execute bit flipped because...they get executed? It also seemed logical, because 644 fixes the problem.

Comment: 0644 is *fewer* permissions than 0664.

Comment: Which is exactly why I'm confused.

Comment: Unless they are directly ran from the cli they are just *read* by the sapi.

Comment: Then I see no reason that they shouldn't be running, other than cPanel is trying to protect files by requiring they be less permissive?

Comment: Also 644 is not executable...

Comment: You're right. I'm a little rusty with server configuration.

Comment: Is apache the owner of the files?

Comment: Hosting companies will typically not allow PHP files to run with permissions set higher than 0644 for security purposes.

Comment: You could add yourself to the sudo and www group.

Are you sure that the files are in a directory with execute permissions?

Files need only read permission and folders need execute permission.

Answer (score 0):

for cpanel, both owner and group have to be the username of the cPanel user.

In a typical cPanel configuration, the root directory for the accounts is home.  Depending on the size of the server, it could be home2/ or home3, etc.

```
chown -R username:username /home/username/public_html/path_to_files
```